# where are the zsh builtin prompt themes reside?

Tags: debian, zsh, prompt

I put the following in my .zshrc -

```
autoload -Uz compinit promptinit
compinit 
promptinit
```

This is also given at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Prompt_themes

While I'm able to cycle between the themes, am wondering where the themes are actually residing at, to read the code of individual themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the code for the `promptinit` function (after it has been called) to see what it runs.

```
% which promptinit | grep path
    local ppath='' name theme
    for theme in $^fpath/prompt_*_setup(N)
% print -l $^fpath/prompt_*_setup(N)
/usr/share/zsh/5.0.8/functions/prompt_adam1_setup
...
```

Comment: in my case it is `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts/prompt_$name_setup` but this might be the way debian does things. Thank you for pointing it out though.